# Generate calendar until special date with one query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Need to generate calendar list until "11-30-2014" in one query. But not all days, only working days(Monday-Friday) and except holidays. Holiday days are storing in `holidays` table. Special table `dual` in oracle DB is used for generate.

```
SELECT to_date(current_date + level-1,'MM-DD-YY') as Calendar
FROM dual, holidays
WHERE to_date(current_date,'MM-DD-YY')+level-1 <= to_date('11-30-14','MM-DD-YY')
AND to_char(to_date(current_date,'MM-DD-YY')+level-1,'D') NOT IN (6,7)
CONNECT BY level <= 365
MINUS
SELECT to_date(data,'MM-DD-YY')
FROM holidays;
```

I did this,but I heart this case can be done with 4 lines. More simple. If someone has any idea how to make this easier then thanks!

Comment: Why are you restricting to 365 days if you want to generate up to 2014-30-11, which is more than a year away? Why are you calling `to_date()` for things that are already dates - you're introducing a dependency on `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, as well as being inefficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a pointless cross join to the `holidays` table in your first `from` clause; you could move your first `where` condition into the `connect by` - presumably without the 365 day restriction, which seems to be at odds with your stated requirement; you are using explicit `to_date()` and implicit `to_char()` conversions to remove the time element of `current_date` which introduces an `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` dependency and would be better with `trunc()` anyway:

```
SELECT TRUNC(current_date) + level - 1 as Calendar
FROM dual
WHERE TO_CHAR(TRUNC(current_date) + level - 1, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
  NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
CONNECT BY TRUNC(current_date) + level - 1 <= date '2014-11-30'
MINUS SELECT data FROM holidays
```

... which is a bit simpler, but not really fewer lines except where I've cheated - but number of lines shouldn't be a metric, it should be readable and understandable, and if a few extra line breaks aids that, who cares?

You could also do this instead, using `not exists` rather than `minus`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT TRUNC(current_date) + level - 1 as Calendar
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY TRUNC(current_date) + level - 1 <= date '2014-11-30'
) t
WHERE TO_CHAR(t.calendar, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM holidays h WHERE h.data = t.calendar)
```

... which also separates the date generation in the inner select block and keeps the filters together, which I think is a bit easier to understand and maintain.